# If choosability of complement is known, can the choosability of the graph be known?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Suppose, we know that $G$ is a regular graph of odd order that is $k$- edge choosable, where $k$ is the degree. Then, is it true that $\overline{G}$ has list edge chromatic number at most $n-k+1$?

I think the answer is yes. This is because, by [Haggkvist-Janssen theorem](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Egoddyn/Courses/800/Resources/Nullstellensatz/HaggkvistJanssenKn.pdf), we have that the complete graph of odd order has list chromatic index $n$, where $n$ is the order. Thus, if edge choosability of $G$ is $k$, then it is straightforward to see that $\overline{G}$ has list edge chromatic number  at most $n-k+1$ by a greedy approach. If this be true, we need to obtain only the list chromatic indices of graphs with $\Delta\ge\frac{n}{2}$, where $\Delta$ is the maximum degree. Am I right, or are there counterexamples? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Is $n$ the number of vertices of $G$? If so, isn't a 5-cycle $G$ 3-edge choosable, but $\bar{G}$ (which is isomorphic to $G$) is not 2-edge choosable?

Comment: @RichardStanley yes, what if I put the upper bound at $n-k+1$? edited the post

Comment: @bof again edited the post. see now

Comment: @bof The reference is not strictly peer-reviewed. So I thought it may not be exact. Hence, you need not have deleted your answer

Comment: I deleted my answer because it seemed to me that I was not telling you anything you did not already know. It was hard to tell what you knew and what you didn't know, because the question, in my opinion, was not formulated with great precision and clarity and was continually being revised.

Comment: The Henderson–Hilton–Jothi result is amazing. I hope the proof is correct and I hope I will be able to understand it. Thanks for calling it to my attention.

Comment: By the way Haggkvist & Janssen proved that $K_n$ is $n$-edge-choosable for **every** $n$, so why is your question only about odd $n$?

Comment: @bof yes, so I just thought that proving that odd order graphs satisfy the chromatic edge choosability is easier than even order